# UIViewcontroller top appears black color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

in my xib i place webview and uitoolbar  ,now when i run that project i can see a small area around 40px of height from top is black and after that the webview is showing.I also have top navigationbar of 41px .I am pushing this nib from another page .

I tried to set webview frame like

```
 webView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
```

no effect  but when i set frame as like below

```
 webView.frame=CGRectMake(0,-41,320,480);
```

now the black part at the top is gone .

what is the reason for that?

check the blank space in landscape mode
[image]

Comment: Well, given the details you've enumerated, this is pretty self-explanatory. If the web view is shifted down by 41 pixels by default, then of course pushing it up 41 pixels will compensate the deviation.

Comment: no no ...due to that my uitoolbar is going up and down when we change the orientaion

Comment: check status bar is hidden or not

Comment: status bar is there ..but when i open that viewcontroller i can see a navigationbar then a webview  ,webview size is same as view frame .but still when i make the navigationbar alpha 0 then i can see that webviw is starting from 41px top instead of 0

Comment: just once for try u remove your navigation bar n check it

Comment: @KanhaiyaSharma its still showing that black color u want screen shots?

Comment: ya i shall want to show

Comment: @KanhaiyaSharma Please check the question

Comment: that top red square shows the blank black color area ,now its in landscape just before it was in portrait mode now i move the webview frame